# How can I build zaptel for ARM?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to cross-compile zaptel driver for Arm
I'm following this project http://svn.astfin.org/software/baps/trunk to build zaptel driver for blackfin arch. 
After building uClinux, oslec and patching [zaptel.patch](http://svn.astfin.org/software/baps/trunk/patch/zaptel.patch) to build extra modules `wcfxs, sport_interface, bfsi`  instead of original one, this command does the magic

```
make -C /home/working/BAPS/uClinux-dist/linux-2.6.x/ SUBDIRS=/home/working/BAPS/zaptel-1.4.3/ modules V=1 ARCH=blackfin CROSS_COMPILE=bfin-uclinux- EXTRA_CFLAGS="-DCONFIG_4FX_SPI_INTERFACE"
```

Build process run successfully, `bfsi.ko, sport_interface.ko, wcfxs.ko, zaptel.ko` generated and useful for my astfin board (well, also the oslec.ko in the previous process).

```
bfsi.ko:            ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, Analog Devices Blackfin, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
sport_interface.ko: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, Analog Devices Blackfin, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
wcfxs.ko:           ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, Analog Devices Blackfin, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
zaptel.ko:          ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, Analog Devices Blackfin, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

So then I want to do the same thing with my arm board (particularly my Beaglebone Black).
Firstly, I completely built [BBB Kernel](http://elinux.org/Building_BBB_Kernel), and then the oslec. I know oslec is also a kernel module but I easily built it.

```
make -C [my bbb kernel] ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- EXTRA_CFLAGS="-I/home/working/AAPS/oslec/kernel -I/home/working/AAPS/oslec/spandsp-0.0.3/src/spandsp" SUBDIRS=/home/working/AAPS/oslec/kernel modules
```

I have the oslec.ko and it looks ok.

```
kernel/oslec.ko: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

But I got stuck in the final step - building zaptel
Here's my make command

`make -C /home/working/AAPS/dl/buildroot-bbb/output/build/linux-3.8.13/\`
 `SUBDIRS=/home/working/AAPS/zaptel-1.4.3/ modules V=1 ARCH=arm\`
`CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1\`
 
`EXTRA_CFLAGS="-DCONFIG_4FX_SPORT_INTERFACE -I/home/working/AAPS/zaptel-1.4.3/staging/usr/include "`
come with error:

```
include/linux/wait.h:159:47: error: ‘TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define wake_up_interruptible(x) __wake_up(x, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE, 1, NULL)
```

I figured out that the constant TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE was defined in `$(my_bbb_kernel)/include/linux/sched.h` and `$(blackfin_uclinux_kernel)/linux-2.6.x/include/linux/sched.h`, but one works (uclinux for blackfin) and one does not (my bbb kernel). I dont know how can they included cause i'm not so familiar with linux kernel module development.
So if anyone have any idea in this case, please give me some instructions or explains.
Best Regards
Loi Dang